# ¿Ocultar contenedor con fadeIn y fadeOut de manera rápida?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Necesito ocultar el contenedor de manera rápida, acá lo esta ocultando pero en forma de desvanecido, como lo puedo ocultar rápido?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>pieza clima</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" CONTENT="30;">

</head>
<body>
  
        <script>
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $(".container-main .img, .medellin, .grado, .dia, .hora").fadeOut(7000);
                  });
        </script>

    <div class="container-main">
            <video autoplay muted loop id="myVideo">
                <source src="img/video1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
            <img src="iconos/Soleado.png" class="img img-1" />
            <h1 class="medellin">Medellín</h1>
            <h1 class="grado">17ºC</h1>
            <h1 class="dia"><script>
                    var meses = new Array ("Enero","Febrero","Marzo","Abril","Mayo","Junio","Julio","Agosto","Septiembre","Octubre","Noviembre","Diciembre");
                    var diasSemana = new Array("Domingo","Lunes","Martes","Miércoles","Jueves","Viernes","Sábado");
                    var f=new Date();
                    document.write(diasSemana[f.getDay()] + ", " + f.getDate() + " de " + meses[f.getMonth()]);
                    </script></h1>
            <h1 class="hora"> <script type="text/javascript">
                var d = new Date();
                document.write(+d.getHours(), ':' +d.getMinutes());
            </script></h1>
      
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Usa las funciones de `.show()` y `.hide()` esas no usan transiciones

Comment: el fadeOut(7000) es para ocultarlo con un retardo, si deseas usa como te comentan Show y Hide: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_hide_show.asp

Comment: Mira, tengo un video que dura 10 segundos, necesito que más o menos a los dos segundos aparezca lo que tengo en el contenedor y a los 8 segundos más o menos se oculte, como lo podría hacer con .show() y .hide()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
<img src="https://us.123rf.com/450wm/rost9/rost91603/rost9160300045/55795097-cuadro-rojo-con-la-reflexi%C3%B3n-interior-3d-ilustraci%C3%B3n.jpg?ver=6" alt="imagen">
<div id="contenido">
        <p>Content above your video</p>
</div>
<style>
.overlay {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:1;
    display:inline,
}
.ocultar{
  display:none;
}
</style>
<script>
  div = document.getElementById('contenido');
  div.setAttribute("class","ocultar");
//se ejecutara despues de 2 segundos
setTimeout(mostrarTexto, 2000);
//se ejecutara despues de 4 segundos
setTimeout(OcultarTexto, 4000);
function mostrarTexto(){
  div = document.getElementById('contenido');
  div.setAttribute("class","overlay");
}
function OcultarTexto(){
div = document.getElementById('contenido');
div.setAttribute("class","ocultar");
}//end function OcultarTexto
</script>
```

Saludos podrias hacer algo como esto, claro no es un video es una imagen y encima de esta a los dos segundo muestro un texto y los 4 segundos lo oculto, usando la funcion setTimeout, para mayor referencia de esto te sugiero revisar la documentacion:

[setTimeout JavaScript](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp)

Ademas uso css para ocultar o mostrar, en vez de ello podrias usar Jquery con el evento show and hide, espero te sirva de guia..!!